# Publisher and Subscriber together problem

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am trying to subscribe and publish at the same time. I tried to follow the suggestions given for similar questions but am not able to publish the data that I am getting using the callback function.  My publisher is created in the constructor of a class and is stored in a member variable.  I am calling the member.publish method in the callback function.   Is this right ?   Also, do I need to run the publish command in a dedicated loop again inside the callback function or the looping because of callback function is enough ?

Here is the error message that I get

[FATAL] [1320088082. 162199274] : ASSERTION FAILED
file = /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/rospp/include/ros/publisher.h
line = 101
cond = false
message =

drive_base /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<         >::operator->() const [with T = ros::Publisher::Impl]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted

Can anybody help understand what is going wrong ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11745/publisher-and-subscriber-together--problem/) by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/737/adesh/) on 2011-10-31**:
Thanks. I got what was going wrong. I was calling a function while the callback  was looping. Because of that,  the publish part (after the function call ) was never getting executed. But I still wonder, why would it show this message in that case.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-10-31**:
I suggest you post the code where this is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you already found the problem.

In answer to your original question: yes, you can publish from a subscriber callback. No extra loop is required.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1